# Минимальная "политика конфиденциальности" для приложения iOS?

Tags: ios, apple, privacy

С некоторых пор Apple стала спрашивать ссылку на политику конфиденциальности для приложений:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Подскажите:

1. Какой минимально возможный текст (на русском/английском) должен размещаться по этой ссылке для примитивного приложения, которое вообще никаких данных и разрешений у пользователя не запрашивает (как пример: игра крестики-нолики, которая даже имя игрока не просит ввести в конце игры)?
2. Нужно ли этот текст размещать на собственном сайте или где-то есть уже основные варианты этих текстов и можно дать ссылку туда?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Я использовал такие тексты. Русский:

> Политика конфиденциальности
>
> 1. Термин “личная информация”, используемый в настоящем документе, определяется как любая информация, которая идентифицирует или может
>      использоваться для идентификации, связи или поиска человека, к
>      которому такая информация относится. Личная информация, которую мы
>      собираем, будет являться предметом настоящей политики
>      конфиденциальности, с вносимыми время от времени поправками.
> 2. Мы не запрашиваем Ваш адрес электронной почты, телефон или какую нибудь информацию о Вас.
> 3. Мы не продаем контент.
> 4. Мы не требуем регистрации.
> 5. Безопасность Вашей персональной информации не будет нарушена.
> 6. Мы не просим информацию о местоположении через наше мобильное приложение.
> 7. Мы не отправляем на электронную почту рассылку новостей.
>
> Контакты
>
> e-mail: myemail@example.com

Английский:

> Privacy Policy
>
> Built the AppName app as a Free app. This service is provided by at no
>   cost and is intended for use as is.
>
> Contact Us
>
> If you have any questions or suggestions about my Privacy Policy, do
>   not hesitate to contact me myemail@example.com.

Аппрув в Apple приложение прошло.

2. В тоже время в интернете достаточно сервисов, которые предлагают подобную платную услугу. Наример:
   https://www.iubenda.com/en/help/401-privacy-policy-for-ios-and-macos-apps